# How much memory assign to the partitions on the installation?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

I want to install Ubuntu on my laptop (500GiB, 4GiB RAM).  I already have Windows 7 and I want to keep it with 100GiB.

Here are some questions:

1. I'm not sure about how much memory assign to `/` and `/home`.

   I think  50 GiB to root and the rest to `/home`, it's that okay? (normal user).
2. Do I really **need** `/boot` and the `swap` partition?
3. what's the difference between logic and primary memory?
4. I don't have any partitions on my disk, I just have `C` with 500gb, do I need to make a partition previous the installation ? I mean to see the `free space` during the installation process.
5. any advice?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install gParted onto a thumb drive http://gparted.org/liveusb.php

Next, run disk defragmenter in Windows, and you need to get 100% defragmented if possible.

Then boot off the usb, and resize your 500GB partition to 100GB.

When that is done you should have about 400GB of free space.

In the installer, there are multiple ways to install.  You want "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7".  It should do everything automatically.

And you don't need to separate partitions anymore.  And you don't need to worrk with logical partitions either.  The installer will take care of everything.

Comment: please mark answer with the check mark.